# Font appears in map file, but pdflatex can't find it

Tags: fonts, pdftex, type1, libertinus

I installed the libertinus-type1 package using the libertinus-type1.tds.zip file from CTAN here: https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-type1 .  I then ran `updmap-sys --enable Map=libertinus.map`.  Then I created the following test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-type1}
\begin{document}
this is a test.
\end{document}
```

and tried to process it with pdflatex. This produces an error about a missing font:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 LibertinusSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for LibertinusSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1.
mktexpk: perhaps LibertinusSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1 is missing from the map file.
```

Looking inside libertinus.map, I see:

```
LibertinusSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1 LibertinusSerif-Regular "AutoEnc_674lrvy3qk43r3lrh7l6fe3tve ReEncodeFont" <[lbts_674lrv.enc <LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb
```

kpsewhich confirms that the pfb and enc files exist:

```
kpsewhich LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb

kpsewhich lbts_674lrv.enc
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertinus-type1/lbts_674lrv.enc
```

and the libertinus.map file is actually included in updmap.cfg:

```
kpsewhich updmap.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg

cat /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg | grep libertinus.map
Map libertinus.map
```

How can I track down why this font isn't working?  I'm way past the end of my knowledge of LaTeX fonts.

**UPDATE:**

Ulrike Fischer's comments led me to the solution by making me realize that pdftex.map wasn't being updated. There was a spurious entry for a non-existent map file in updmap.cfg that caused updmap-sys to fail.

The first time I ran it to add the libertinus.map it spat out a lot of messages and I missed the error messages. I was only able to see them again by manually editing updmap.cfg to remove libertinus.map and then re-running `updmap-sys --enable Map=libertinus.map` . Just doing a `--disable` apparently isn't enough to trigger re-building all the maps, and I was hesitant to do a `--force`, since I wasn't sure what was going on.  Once I saw the error, I manually removed the spurious entry (and removed the entry for libertinus.map) then re-ran updmap-sys, and everything works now.  Thanks to everyone for the advice.

Comment: why from ctan rather than installing it via texlive or miktex package manager??, installing by hand in the standard tree is always risky as the package manager will not know the files are theer and will over-write the map files etc on any update

Comment: you seem to be using a linux supplied tex so `sudo apt get texlive-fonts-extra` or whatever package manager you use at the linux system level should probably do the right thing

Comment: Regarding David Carlisle's comment: Good point, but for now this is just for testing.   I originally had the files in a separate tree, but found the same problem there.  Installing via tlmgr would be problematic because this is a RHEL-based system where all of the texlive stuff is installed via rpm packages. After I figure out what's wrong I'll move things back out of the standard tree.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, this isn't in the available packages for the distribution, but I have tried packages from similar distributions (fedora), and the results were the same.

Comment: does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=libertinus.map}`  to your document?

Comment: Yes! Adding the pdfmapfile makes it work.  Is there a way to have this happen by default, without needing to add that line?

Comment: sure, I only wanted to test if your installation is basically ok. You probably have two pdftex.map files and updmap-sys updated the one but you are using the other. Look into the log-file. At the end it should show the path of your pdftex.map, compare that with the files updmap-sys writes. If they are different delete the local version and try again.

Comment: If you ever decide to compile with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`, then install package `libertinus-otf` with its OpenType fonts.

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't be installing stuff by hand into `/usr/share` on Linux. It would be better to install into `TEXMFLOCAL`. `updmap-sys` will still find the files, but you won't conflict with your distro's package manager.